OpenCV (Python) Draw on video manually
The image shows two green rectangles. I need to manually draw each rectangle in the video and have the coordinates saved in area1 and area2 of the script (main), respectively. I attach the two scripts I use (main and tracker).enter image description here
I attach the two scripts (main and tracker)
main
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from ultralytics import YOLO
from tracker import*
import cvzone
import numpy as np

model=YOLO('yolov8s.pt')

def RGB(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE :  
        point = [x, y]
        print(point)

cv2.namedWindow('RGB')
cv2.setMouseCallback('RGB', RGB)
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('p.mp4')

my_file = open("coco.txt", "r")
data = my_file.read()
class_list = data.split("\n") 
#print(class_list)

count=0

tracker=Tracker()

area1=[(494,289),(505,499),(578,496),(530,292)]
area2=[(548,290),(600,496),(637,493),(574,288)]

going_out={}
going_in={}
counter1=[]
counter2=[]
while True:    
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
#    frame = stream.read()

#    count += 1
#    if count % 3 != 0:
#        continue
    frame=cv2.resize(frame,(1020,500))
   

    results=model.predict(frame)
 #   print(results)
    a=results[0].boxes.data
    px=pd.DataFrame(a).astype("float")
#    print(px)
    
    list=[]
    for index,row in px.iterrows():
#        print(row)
 
        x1=int(row[0])
        y1=int(row[1])
        x2=int(row[2])
        y2=int(row[3])
        d=int(row[5])
        
        c=class_list[d]
        if 'person' in  c:
            list.append([x1,y1,x2,y2])
    bbox_idx=tracker.update(list)
    for bbox in bbox_idx:
        x3,y3,x4,y4,id=bbox
        result=cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.array(area2,np.int32),((x4,y4)),False)
        if result>=0:
           going_out[id]=(x4,y4)
        if id in going_out:
           result1=cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.array(area1,np.int32),((x4,y4)),False)
           if result1>=0:
               cv2.circle(frame,(x4,y4),7,(255,0,255),-1)
               cv2.rectangle(frame,(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(255,255,255),2)
               cvzone.putTextRect(frame,f'{id}',(x3,y3),1,1)
               if counter1.count(id)==0:
                  counter1.append(id)
               
        result2=cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.array(area1,np.int32),((x4,y4)),False)
        if result2>=0:
           going_in[id]=(x4,y4)
        if id in going_in:
           result3=cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.array(area2,np.int32),((x4,y4)),False)
           if result3>=0:
               cv2.circle(frame,(x4,y4),7,(255,0,255),-1)
               cv2.rectangle(frame,(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(255,0,0),2)
               cvzone.putTextRect(frame,f'{id}',(x3,y3),1,1)
               if counter2.count(id)==0:
                  counter2.append(id)        

    out_c=(len(counter1))
    in_c=(len(counter2))
    cvzone.putTextRect(frame,f'OUT:{out_c}',(50,60),2,2)
    cvzone.putTextRect(frame,f'IN:{in_c}',(50,160),2,2)
    
    cv2.polylines(frame,[np.array(area1,np.int32)],True,(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.polylines(frame,[np.array(area2,np.int32)],True,(0,255,0),2)
             
    cv2.imshow("RGB", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tracker
import math


class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
        # Store the center positions of the objects
        self.center_points = {}
        # Keep the count of the IDs
        # each time a new object id detected, the count will increase by one
        self.id_count = 0


    def update(self, objects_rect):
        # Objects boxes and ids
        objects_bbs_ids = []

        # Get center point of new object
        for rect in objects_rect:
            x, y, w, h = rect
            cx = (x + x + w) // 2
            cy = (y + y + h) // 2

            # Find out if that object was detected already
            same_object_detected = False
            for id, pt in self.center_points.items():
                dist = math.hypot(cx - pt[0], cy - pt[1])

                if dist < 35:
                    self.center_points[id] = (cx, cy)
#                    print(self.center_points)
                    objects_bbs_ids.append([x, y, w, h, id])
                    same_object_detected = True
                    break

            # New object is detected we assign the ID to that object
            if same_object_detected is False:
                self.center_points[self.id_count] = (cx, cy)
                objects_bbs_ids.append([x, y, w, h, self.id_count])
                self.id_count += 1

        # Clean the dictionary by center points to remove IDS not used anymore
        new_center_points = {}
        for obj_bb_id in objects_bbs_ids:
            _, _, _, _, object_id = obj_bb_id
            center = self.center_points[object_id]
            new_center_points[object_id] = center

        # Update dictionary with IDs not used removed
        self.center_points = new_center_points.copy()
        return objects_bbs_ids


What are we supposed to do with these scripts?

I need to manually draw each rectangle in the video and have the coordinates saved in area1 and area2 of the script (main), respectively. I attach the two scripts I use (main and tracker).

Yes, I saw the two scripts. Stack Overflow is a site where you can ask a specific technical question and people can answer the question. You did not ask a question so far.

Please also review the tags, while you [edit] your question to improve it. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Thank you for the comments on this learning process. My question is: How do I draw two rectangles in the video manually and have the coordinates automatically placed in area1 and area2 in the main script?
